# google chrome gpu error in electron build

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron

I have an electron app that works fine in development. But when I build to linux-x64, and try to open the executable, the program crashes with the error:

```
[xxxx:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

According to this page, https://simpleit.rocks/linux/ubuntu/fixing-common-google-chrome-gpu-process-error-message-in-linux/ this is a common problem in chrome-linux, and can be solved with the command:

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
```

However, I don't know how/where to implement this inside electron.

In reality, my app is a react project, converted into an electron project by by adding the following file as the entry. This is the only electron related file in my project (meaning it was 100% webapp aside from this).

```
const electron = require('electron'),
  app = electron.app,
  BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
   
const path = require('path'),
  isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
   
let mainWindow;
   
const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 480, height: 320 })
  const appUrl = isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' :
    `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
  mainWindow.loadURL(appUrl)
  mainWindow.maximize()
  mainWindow.setFullScreen(true)
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => mainWindow = null)
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // Follow OS convention on whether to quit app when
  // all windows are closed.
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') { app.quit() }
})
app.on('activate', () => {
  // If the app is still open, but no windows are open,
  // create one when the app comes into focus.
  if (mainWindow === null) { createWindow() }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("disable-software-rasterizer");
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-gpu');
```

This should do the trick.

Adding those to the commendLine to your electron app.

This bug that I read helped me:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/28164